# Disable "Tap to Click" in a XCode cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, system-preferences

The system preferences of Mac OS X have a option of magic track pad to just touch the track pad without actually press to do a click. It is called "Tap to Click". Is there a way to disable this functionality in my application?

I'm using XCode 4.5 and the project is a cocoa application. The Mac OS X is the Lion version.

Comment: For ios, it works with these codes

To disable touch

    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

To enable touch

    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

Kindly check whether this thing is available for Mac applications

Answer (score 0):

for UIWebview ,to switch off the default contextual menu of UIWebView. This is easy because we only need to set the CSS property “-webkit-touch-callout” to “none” for the body element of the web page. We can do this using JavaScript in the UIWebView delegate method “webViewDidFinishLoad:”…

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
}
```

for mac ..there should be something like this...not sure